# Offer to queue with some initial display

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-stream, playframework-2.5

I want to offer to queue a string sent in load request after some initial delay say 10 seconds.

If the subsequent request is made with some short interval delay(1 second) then everything works fine, but if it is made continuously like from a script then there is no delay.

Here is the sample code.

```
 def load(randomStr :String) = Action { implicit request =>

  Source.single(randomStr)
    .delay(10 seconds, DelayOverflowStrategy.backpressure)
    .map(x =>{
    println(x)
    queue.offer(x)

  })
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)

  Ok("")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure that this is the correct way of doing what you want. There are some things you need to reconsider:

1. a delayed source has an initial buffer capacity of 16 elements. You can increase this with `addAttributes(initialBuffer)`
2. In your case the buffer cannot actually become full because every time you provide just one element.
3. Who is the caller of the Action? You are defining a `DelayOverflowStrategy.backpressure` strategy but is the caller able to handle this?
4. On every call of the action you are creating a Stream consisting of one element, how is the backpressure here helping? It is applied on the stream processing and not on the *offering* to the queue